# How to install ROS2 Bouncy from source

Tags: ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to install ROS2 Bouncy from source on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I've been following these install instructions: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Linux-Development-Setup and only changed the --rosdistro parameter from crystal to bouncy in "Install dependencies using rosdep" section. However, I keep getting crystal as an output of 'printenv ROS_DISTRO" command after sourcing the workspace.

What else needs to be changed in order to obtain Bouncy source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320563/how-to-install-ros2-bouncy-from-source/) by [nickcage](https://answers.ros.org/users/36873/nickcage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2019-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'd most likely have to change the URL to the `ros2.repos` file in the [Get ROS 2 code](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Linux-Development-Setup/#get-ros-2-code) section from pointing to the `latest-release` to `bouncy` (which are basically two different branches in the `ros2/ros2` repository).

So:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/release-latest/ros2.repos
```

should be:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/bouncy/ros2.repos
```

See also the [Maintaining a Source Checkout of ROS 2](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Maintaining-a-Source-Checkout/) page.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-08**:
You might be able to use `rosinstall_generator` as well:

```
rosinstall_generator --tar --deps --rosdistro=bouncy  ros_core > bouncy.rosinstall
```

But I'm not sure whether that will result in a successful build on Xenial (as Xenial support for Bouncy is basically "Tier 2").

**Comment by [nickcage](https://answers.ros.org/users/36873/nickcage/) on 2019-04-08**:
I used the first solution you proposed and it worked, thank you.